# SDL Window pops up, but it's blank and totally irresponsive

Tags: c++, sdl

I am 100% sure I have set the SDL library to work properly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv\[\]) {

    // Initializing SDL

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Window *window = 0;

    // Creating the window       

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
            SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    // Just so I can see the window because it goes away immediately.    

    SDL_Delay(5000);

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to know if this problem is from my system.

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen when you don't process the OS event queue for 5 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create the window, you need to handle events using `SDL_PollEvent`. Instead of `SDL_Delay(5000)`, do something like this:

```
    // ... setup (SDL_Init, SDL_CreateWindow, etc.)
    SDL_Event event;
    for(;;) {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch(event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    goto done;
            }
        }
    }
done:
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
```

Comment: Maybe add a small delay so that this does not spin as fast as possible.

Comment: But I dont understand what the "for(;;)" does. Can you explain a little please?

Comment: for(;;) is just the syntax I prefer for infinite loops. You can also use while(true), while(1), etc.